# Do I have to re-compile everytime I add a new device for ad-hoc installation?

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, adhoc

I have created an ad-hoc provision profile for my iPhone application. Everytime I add a new device, do I need to re-compile my application so that it can be distributed? This is VERY tedious.

Comment: Yes. How often are you adding a new device, and how long can compilation take?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. When you compile your application it is code signed with the *.mobileprovision you have selected for the current build configuration. Each time you add a new device, it changes the *.mobileprovision file to allow for that unique UDID, so you need to both recompile AND reinstall your *.mobileprovision (by dragging into iTunes again) in order for the new devices to run the Ad Hoc distro.

Comment: Continuing the thought, remember that ad hoc distribution is not designed to be an official distribution mechanism. It's designed to be a "hey, can you test this for me?" distribution mechanism. If you're constantly adding new devices, then you're very likely using it for things Apple explicitly doesn't want to you do, and so is not going to make easy.