# Must I share the Apple Provisioning Profile to all our developers always if I add a new device?

Tags: ios, profile, provisioning, adhoc

We have an Apple iOS-Developer-Account. If I add a new device to an existing Adhoc-Dist. Provisioning Profile, then must install this updated Profile all our developers on their devices or only the developer with the new device? Must I update/rebuild the app always again, after I edited the Provisioning Profile?

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Check the last comment in my answer for the link to how to add the app through iTunes.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Your new team member is the only one that needs to install the provisioning profile the rest of the team just need to refresh. It will not effect the apps at all. Here is the link to the docs that explains it, specially the first paragraph.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificatesandProvisioningAssets/MaintainingCertificatesandProvisioningAssets.html

Here is another link that clearly states that the team members may need to refresh their profile.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

> If you use the team provisioning profile, you need to regenerate it after approving the certificate. Xcode regenerates the team provisioning profile whenever a team member refreshes provisioning profiles in Xcode. Afterward, all other team members need to refresh their provisioning profiles to download the latest team provisioning profile.

Comment: any developer that'll want to compile a new version of the app will also need the provisioning profile, unless I'm totally-misusing it

Comment: @Nimrod, If there is a new version of the app yes, but in the case of this question we are just talking about new member being added to the team not creating a new version of the app

Comment: I added the text from that link. The two things seemed contradictory, but I don't think its necessary to refresh the profile. The old one should still work for any devices included in it. It seemed more like you have to refresh if you want to get the new profile, which is kind of obvious anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How is the case if a team member have not xcode, because he is only a testperson?

Comment: You need to send him the app and then he needs to drag and drop the project to his iTunes and then sync it. The whole detail of how to implement the project through iTunes is in the docs. Here is the link to how to add the app through iTunes. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html

Comment: We use the Adhoc Distribution. I send the new member the provisioning profile and the app link. I need not integrate the new profile in the app first? If I edit the app, then I must integrate the new profile in the app and send the profile to all members?

Comment: Yes to the first one and the no to second question. Team members just need to refresh the profiles through xcode and that's it. Since you are just modifying the provisioning profile not creating a new one. If you edit the app then you need the new provisioning profile and then yes.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the regular developer provisioning profile (not enterprise ad-hoc) you'll need to release a new version of the app every time you add a new device to the provisioning profile. This is a bit bothersome (from my experience).

If any of the other developers in the team will want to release a new version with the new provisioning profile he'll also need to install it.

You'll get used to it after the 10th time :)

Comment: btw - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284878/do-i-have-to-re-compile-everytime-i-add-a-new-device-for-ad-hoc-installation

Comment: No you dont need, refreehing the provisioning profile is enough

Comment: @TussLászló take a look at the date of the answer and the question. That's before xCode 5 was out so the steps I wrote were relevant